# Video + Audio Recorder Android

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camera

My Goal is to capture Video using Android Camera and Record
Voice from Mic.

I googled code but couldn't get any working example or code.

what I've tried is

---

```
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes

        recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240); 
        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
```

---

I'm getting a RuntimeException

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.

on the following line

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
```

tried with replacing

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Please post the error you got.

Comment: before checking the code, are you trying this on a real device?

Comment: @alextsc java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.

Comment: @Sherif Yes .. Im working on real device itself

Comment: +1 good question with nice description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to set permissions in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: There is no such permission as RECORD_VIDEO, not sure if it was removed at some stage after your post

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug within android. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4075

You can just try this:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(0); // Or 1, don't know which Enum is right.
```

Because there is a mismatch in Enums.

Comment: You can try to use the library: `vrecorder` but I do not have a fix for this bug.